# Create xml file by a list of xpath

Tags: xslt

I have a source- and target list of xpaths, where each list is based on their own schema. For each source path exists a target path. For example I have the source list [/shiporder/shipfrom/name, /shiporder/address/city] and the target list [/root/Seller/Country, /root/Seller/City] where the order of the lists connects the source-path with the target-path. Now I can create simple and well readable stylesheets which applies each source path and creates a output with respect to the target-path. For /shiporder/shipfrom/name the [stylesheet](http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuL/16) is:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shiporder"/>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
 <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shipfrom"/>
 </root>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipfrom">
    <Seller>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
    </Seller>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipfrom/name">
    <Country>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </Country>
</xsl:template>
```

and for `/shiporder/address/city` the [stylesheet](http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuL/15) is:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shiporder"/>
  </xsl:template> 
 <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
 <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="address"/>
 </root>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/shiporder/address">
    <Seller>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="city"/>        
    </Seller>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/shiporder/address/city">
    <City>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </City>
 </xsl:template>
```

After creation I apply both stylesheets on an arbitrary source xml file based on the source schema e.g.:

```
<shiporder>
  <shipfrom>
    <name>orderperson1</name>
  </shipfrom>
  <address>
    <city>London</city>
  </address>
  <address>
    <city>Berlin</city>
  </address>
</shiporder>
```

Now I like to combine both stylesheets as easy as possible to one [stylesheet](http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuL/14).

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very clear.  Please show the two different XML inputs and the desired output for each one.

Comment: @JimGarrison I tried to simplify my question, let me know if there is something unclear. And also let me know if you have a better suggestion for a headline.

Comment: what is your expected output if all elements are present? as in your sample input XML?

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen if all elements present the expected output is represented in the first [link](http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuL/14).

Comment: @StellaMaris Please check these links (http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuQ, http://xsltransform.net/bwdwrN, http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxS).

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen In your solution the same problem will appear that also comes with tmakita solution. If the source and target lists become more complex the branching (`choose`) in the templates become realy complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate XPath using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332569/generate-xpath-using-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Based from what I understand in your question, I came up with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="shiporder">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="address">
        <!-- store the name node to a variable -->
        <xsl:variable name="country" select="../shipfrom/name"/>
        <Seller>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <!-- check if the variable is not empty,
                 if not, output the contents under the node Country -->
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space($country)!=''">
                <Country>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$country"/>
                </Country>
            </xsl:if>
        </Seller>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="city">
        <City>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </City>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="shipfrom">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- check for following-sibling address nodes, 
                 if none found, delete the node -->
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::address"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Seller>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </Seller>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="shipfrom/name">
        <Country>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Country>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first stylesheet outputs the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <Seller>
      <Country>orderperson1</Country>
   </Seller>
</root>
```

Also your second stylesheet outputs folowing XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <Seller>
      <City>London</City>
   </Seller>
   <Seller>
      <City>Berlin</City>
   </Seller>
</root>
```

If you want to produce two output results by one stylesheet module, you should introduce parameter xsl:param that controls output. I made the minimum stylesheet that realizes this requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="prmOutputShipForm" select="'yes'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pOutputShipForm" select="$prmOutputShipForm = 'yes'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shiporder"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
        <root>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$pOutputShipForm">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="shipfrom"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="address"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipfrom">
        <Seller>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
        </Seller>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipfrom/name">
        <Country>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Country>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder/address">
        <Seller>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="city"/>        
        </Seller>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder/address/city">
        <City>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </City>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By setting OutputShipForm="yes/no", you can control output XML result.

Comment: Thx tmakita, but it I'm looking for something else, because assume I have a third `/shiporder/elem3/xy` and fourth `/shiporder/elem4/xy` element which I want to add in the same way the branching gets to complex.

Comment: @StellaMaris Could you specify concrete input XML file that you want to handle? I think above stylesheet modification works at least for your input XML example.

Comment: The source xml file could be that arbitrary that you will find at least the root node `shiporder`. All the other elements which given as xpath in the source list are not required but it could be possible that you will find them in the source xml.

Comment: @StellaMaris Probably I'm missing what you *DO* want to do about the stylesheet. Currently xsl:template/@match attributes reflects the source XML file element structure. Do you want to exclude this dependency?

Comment: I edited my post again and recognized that I didn't sorted out that there is more then one possibility to combine the output of both stylesheets above.